# Why is indirect speech marked by modus instead of tempus in German?

Tags: history, indirect-speech

If marked, most (according to Wikipedia) european languages use tempus instead of modus for indirect speech. Actually i think this is more intuitive too, as something **was** said by another person. Also, in colloquial German many people often simply use the *Indikativ* for indirect speech.

So where does the German "exception to the rule" come from? Was the *tempus* once also used for this purpose in distinct German regions? Does it have some advantage to use *modus*?

Comment: A very interesting question!

Comment: This would be a good question for http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ too…

Comment: German is not really an exception: the subjunctive/conjunctive and optative are very common in Greek and Latin. Cf. *dicit Romanos urbam delevisse quam nuper oppugnavissent*, and the Greek *optativus obliquus*. Often tense is used in conjunction with mood in Latin. But the indicative is rare in indirect speech in Latin, at least in the classical era.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but I'd like to point to this academic paper by Yukik Shioya ([22 pages PDF download](http://eprints.lib.hokudai.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2115/25862/1/19_P11-22.pdf)) about the expression of scepticism in German's indirect speech:

The author confronts these sentences

> a. Maria hat gesagt: "Ich bin 18 Jahre alt."
> b. Maria hat gesagt, dass sie 18 Jahre alt ist.
> c. Maria hat gesagt, dass sie 18 Jahre alt sei.
> d. Maria hat gesagt, dass sie 18 Jahre alt wäre.
>
> a) ist die direkte Rede. b) ist die indirekte Rede mit dem Verb im Indikativ, c) mit dem Verb im Konjunktiv I, d) mit dem Verb im Konjunktiv II. Es gibt einen entscheidenden Unterschied zwischen a) und b), c), d). Was wirklich in a) von Maria gesagt wird, ist nur die zitierte Stelle, d. h. "ich bin 18 Jahre alt". Sind Maria und "ich" eine und dieselbe Person, muss mindestens ein Hörer in diesem Raum anwesend sein, und sie äußert, .. ich bin 18 Jahre alt".
>
> Solch ein Satz und eine Szene kann man leicht z. B. in einem Roman finden. Dagegen können die ganzen Sätze von (b,c,d) tatsächlich in einer konkreten Situation bei einem Hörer von diesem Sprecher gesprochen werden. Der Sprecher äußert auch den Hauptsatz. Außer der erwähnten Person sind normalerweise ein Sprecher und mindestens ein Hörer anwesend. In diesem Fall ist es unbestimmt, ob Maria da ist oder nicht.
>
> Der Sprecher gibt die Äußerung von seinem eigenen Standpunkt wieder. Es gibt natürlich viele Möglichkeiten, z. B. er ist für den Inhalt des zitierten Satzes oder dagegen, oder er hat die bestimmte Absicht, dass er den Hörer herausfordern will. Über die vom Sprecher   zitierte Information kann nur der Sprecher verfügen. Er kann da für oder dagegen sein, sich distanzieren oder nicht, oder er kann auch die Information nach seiner Meinung übertreiben. Dabei legt er Nachdruck sowohl auf den Komplementsatz als auch den Hauptsatz, der   auch vom Sprecher geäußert wird, während beim echten Berichten manchmal die Hörer ausschließlich am Inhalt des zitierten Satzes Interesse haben.
>
> Die sogenannte Skepsis in  der indirekten Rede zählt m. E. zu einer von diesen Möglichkeiten.